# Can a Service Fabric stateless service notify other instances?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric

I have an Azure Service Fabric application with one stateless service. I have multiple virtual machines running multiple instances of this service.

Is there a way for one instance to notify all other instances that something happened? I was thinking about using Azure Service Bus to subscribe all instances for some topic, and raise a message when an event occurs. Is there a better way?

Comment: You could also use service fabric services to do this. Try [this pub/sub service](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.PubSubActors)

Comment: Can you elaborate the scenario? What kind of services, the purpose of the notification, will be better to give any suggestion

Comment: my case is: when all instances start they get version number as parameter.Then all process request using this number and only one some request cause version change. I want when one instance process such request all instance to change their version number. I was thinking about using stateful service but this will cause performance issue because i don't know from the request info if this request will cause version change or not.So i don't know if i must redirect his request to primary or secondary replica.